# How to achieve same output after migrating from jackson to gson as json processor?

Tags: json, rest, jackson, gson

I am developing a restful webservices using resteasy. Earlier, the provider was jackson.
And the result output is

```
[
    {
        "status": {
            "id": 22,
            "name": "VERIFY",
            "note": ""
        }
    },
    {
        "status": {
            "id": 23,
            "name": "ACCEPTED",
            "note": ""
        }
    },
    {
        "status": {
            "id": 24,
            "name": "POSTPONED",
            "note": "for cancel update"
        }
    },
    {
        "status": {
            "id": 29,
            "name": "AMC(NEW)"
        }
    },
    {
        "status": {
            "id": 30,
            "name": "AMC(ASSIGNED)"
        }
    }
]
```

Later, we moved to gson as provider. http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2012/11/02/integrating-gson-into-a-jax-rs-based-application/

The output change as :

```
[
    {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "DISABLE"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "ENABLE"
    },
    {
        "id": 31,
        "name": "REJECTED",
        "note": ""
    },
    {
        "id": 25,
        "name": "ASSIGNED"
    }
]
```

The class definition

```
package com.apt.common.web.pojo;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Status {
    Integer id;
    String name;
    private String note;
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Status other = (Status) obj;
        if (id == null) {
            if (other.id != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    public String getNote() {
        return note;
    }

    public void setNote(String note) {
        this.note = note;
    }

}
```

Output is totally different.

Using jackson

```
{
    "status": {
        "id": 22,
        "name": "VERIFY",
        "note": ""
    }
}
```

using gson

```
{
    "id": 0,
    "name": "DISABLE"
}
```

Code for generating json using gson is

```
Gson gson=new Gson();

Type fooType = new TypeToken<List<Status>>() {}.getType();

return gson.toJson(statuses,fooType);
```

How can i achieve the same output using gson?

Comment: Could you show how you serialize "statuses" using Jackson?

Comment: earlier  the return type of method is List<Status> during jackson. We simply return statuses. But, for gson, i make changes and return type of method is string and above code is used for serialization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess that in order to achieve the same result using Gson, you'll need another class to *wrap* your `Status` class, with an attribute called `status`, because what Gson includes in the serialized JSON are **the names of the attributes, not the names of the classes**!

So you'll need something like:

```
public class MyClass {
    private Status status;
    //...
}
```

And then in the serialization:

```
//...
Type fooType = new TypeToken<List<MyClass>>() {}.getType();
//...
```

---

In other words, for Gson, this JSON piece:

```
{
    "status": {
        "id": 22,
        "name": "VERIFY",
        "note": ""
    }
}
```

represents this class structure:

```
class MyClass
    Status status;

class Status
    int id;
    String name;
    String note;
```

---

If you don't want to create another class, you can always write a [custom serializer](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Writing-a-Serializer) for your `Status` class...